How to use other services when using the airflow docker image?
I am just starting with airflow. I took a course in which the teacher used an unofficial image of airflow:  puckel/docker-airflow together with other images of jupyter, postgres and minio in a docker-compose.yml.
However now there is an official docker version of airflow. This one has a docker compose yaml file much more complicated with services:

postgress
redis
airflow-webserver
airflow-scheduler
airflow-worker
airflow-triggerer
airflow-init
airflow-cli
flower

My question is, if I want to have an environment similar to the one I had in the course:

I suppose I should have two services of postgress, shouldn't I?
Should I edit the yaml file to include all the services?
Or is there another "correct" way to work this


No you don’t need 2 Postgres service and yes you have to edit yaml file to launch all the services from one command.

I see. I asked because I was told that the Postgress is configured specifically for Airflow's metadata database, so although possible it was recommended to use a separate instance for my needs.

You can just add one more database in Postgres don’t use the one for airflow
